# PhoneGap + android: 2 'www' folder in source code: which to modify?

Tags: android, cordova

When create from scratch a phonegap 3 application, i add platform android and buid + emulate.

See here, official getting started guide: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface

I start to modify code and I notice that there is a 'www' folder under "hello" main directory, and one under platforms\android\assets

Which one must I modify ?

If then I add another platform ? My modification to code will be passed to other platform's code ?

[image]

Comment: The assets one is the android specific and outer is the cross platform code!!!

Comment: So to start working android + blackberry + ios, must I mod the 'main' www folder and NOT the platform specific code? Why Eclipse ADT COMPILE and RUN android version from platform specific WITHOUT take in consideration the changes i made in main(cross platform) www folder ?

Comment: the snapshot you provided is just a snapshot, to keep the outer www as plug and play across various platforms, actually you would not refer the outer www but instead copy the content of the outer www into the assets www for each platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the files in the first "www" folder (in your main directory).

Each `phonegap run android` will overwrite the stuff in "platforms/android".

Comment: do you know if this www folder in the main directory should contain a phonegap.js as well ? or cordova.js ? I don't know why I have both in my android/assets/www folder .. I though I was using either one of those.
Thanks

Comment: You don't need them in your main www folder, they'll be created by phonegap. And they don't differ anyway, so you can use just one of them :)