# Apache Cordova and ADT - Update 'www' folder

Tags: android, cordova, adt, cordova-3

I am developing an Android app using [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) 3.6.0.
I have followed the instructions available [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0//guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) and [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) to create, build and run my app.

I realized there are two folders which store HTML, CSS and JS files: `www` and `platforms/android/assets/www`:

[image]

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18033623/1426227), I should modify only `www` because the command `$ cordova run android` will overwrite `platforms/android/assets/www`.

When I run my app through ADT, the folder `platforms/android/assets/www` is not updated.

How can I make ADT update this directory? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked answer is correct. You should only modify the content of the root `www` folder.
 But you will have to *build* your app before you run it to make your changes take effect in the `platforms/android/assets/www` folder by running:

```
   $ cordova build
```

or `cordova build android`.

Answer (score 0):

FIRST SET OF WWW folder:
  it contains your customized file ,from which you are developing the application.U must make the changes here.

SECOND SET OF WWW folder:
   these are generated when u install a plugin with sample.(A working example)